# Play Framework Error: This exception has been logged with id 6k8i0i7j7

Tags: java, playframework

I am completed building a website in Play framework. The website is deployed at server. But, I am facing some random occurring issue like this one..

> Oops, an error occured
>
> This exception has been logged with id 6k8hohpbh.

Why is this error occurring?

I got the stack trace that looks like this

> 2014-11-18 11:00:54,810 [http-listener-1(5)] ERROR play -
>
> @6k8hohpb6 Internal Server Error (500)
>
> Execution exception RuntimeException occured : play.mvc.Http$Request
>   not found by javassist [134]
>
> play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException: play.mvc.Http$Request not
>   found by javassist [134]  at
>   play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:236)     at
>   play.server.ServletWrapper$ServletInvocation.execute(ServletWrapper.java:578)
>     at play.Invoker$Invocation.run(Invoker.java:282)    at
>   play.server.ServletWrapper$ServletInvocation.run(ServletWrapper.java:569)
>     at play.Invoker.invokeInThread(Invoker.java:72)     at
>   play.server.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:144)   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: play.mvc.Http$Request not found by
>   javassist [134]   at javassist.runtime.Desc.getClassType(Desc.java:156)
>     at javassist.runtime.Desc.getType(Desc.java:122)    at
>   javassist.runtime.Desc.getType(Desc.java:78)  at
>   controllers.AppController._checkAuthenticityToken(AppController.java:407)
>     at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:509)    at
>   play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:483)
>     at
>   play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:478)
>     at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.handleBefores(ActionInvoker.java:327)     at
>   play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:141)     ... 34 more

Comment: Internal Server Error (500) usually has something to do with your server. Perhaps unhandled exception, or wrong logic in the code.

Comment: Please provide more information about your deployment.

Comment: in my case it was some DB issue where some filed was null for some record.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the same production app on your dev machine : if you get no error, then maybe production database can be the problem. 
In my case I had this error but my production database did not have the right permissions to access one table; also some tables did not exist on prod machine while they did on dev machine. Fixing the database issues solved the problem.

Also : to handle exceptions you can use play's action composition to call any action method wrapped in a try/catch and log the error (in file, database and send an email...)